# Looping through object attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm not sure how to correctly phrase the question but I have a model for a photo gallery:

```
class PhotoGallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    collection = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.FileField(upload_to =f'pics/gallery/{collection}')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and I'm trying to figure out a way to get images separately from each collection - views.py:

```
def photo_gallery(request):
    form = GalleryForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            images = request.FILES.getlist('images')
            collection = form.cleaned_data['collection']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            for image in images:
                PhotoGallery.objects.create(img=image, collection=collection, title=title)
    images = PhotoGallery.objects.all()
    
    #not what i think it is - just hoping it could make what i want to do clearer
    context = [collection.img for collection in images]
    return render(request, 'photos/photos.html', context)
```

I haven't been able to find much info in the docs or anywhere online about this. I'm wondering if the solution would be to have a separate model for each collection but even then I'd run into issues if I wanted to add a new collection.

So any suggestions on how I could do this would be appreciated. Is there perhaps an object method where I could do `PhotoGallery.objects.something()`

Comment: You want list of images grouped by collection name?

Comment: @TrueGopnik Yes

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: @TrueGopnik I'm using AWS S3 for storage and heroku postgesql for the actual database

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL you can user ArrayAgg and group your images by collection. Something like PhotoGallery.objects.values('collection').annotate(pictures=ArrayAgg('img')).order_by('collection') should do the trick

Comment: With your current PhotoGallery model, each PhotoGallery only contains one img. I'd expect a 'gallery' to contain multiple images. Therefore a separate Image model and the PhotoGallery model having a foreignkey relation with the Image model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

```
galleries_with_selected_collection = PhotoGallery.objects.filter(collection=selected_collection)

# context must be a dict, not a list
context = {
    'galleries': galleries_with_selected_collection
}
```

You're pulling in PhotoGallery objects not images or collections. Those are attributes of your PhotoGallery. So you'll need to grab photo galleries with your chosen collection, then grab their image attribute.

And to clarify about creating a model for each collection:

You can split your collections into a Collection model. You wouldn't need to create a new model for each collection, you just add each collection instance to the collection table. Then your photo gallery would have a foreign key to the collection. I would probably go one step further and separate your images into their own model too.

Comment: Just to add that the context must be a dictionary, not a list. Django will raise an exception if `render()` receives a list as context. I appreciate that the code in the question is written this way, but thought I would clarify